# Wrong classification to multiple classes with different fraction of classes

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, text-classification

I've encouraged with next problem:
I'm trying to classify a lot of text documents.

There are 20 classes: 1 normal, 19 - abnormal.
When I use Naïve bayes classification I have the following result: classification works well for 19 classes, but for "normal" class I got many misclassification errors: almost all cases in "normal" category were classified as other (non-normal) category.

There are my questions:

- How should I select training set for "normal" class?  (Now, I just fit
  to classifier set of text with "normal" category, with 1/20
  proportion).
- Can classifier be specified this way: if probability of belonging to 
  some class less then certain threshold then classifier must set up
  category for this sample (e.g. normal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to have the full picture but It seems like you have in fact only 2 classes "normal" and "abnormal" which are unbalanced in volume and thus prior.

To answer your first question, in that situation, I would try to over-sampling your normal class for training (passing same "normal" instances multiple times to  "fake" bigger volume) and see if it improves your performances.

I don't get your second question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it has got great improvement!
I try explain: For example, I use for training set 1000 examples for each category. So, I use 1000 examples for 19 (abnormal categories) and 19 000 for normal category.
It helps balanced training set and get great improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably unbalanced number of instances for each classes cause the problem. You need to define some kind of prior over the final class estimation to evade the problem of unbalanced instances and you need to fine tune this prior's exogenous parameter by cross-validation. I guess Dirichlet Prior is in use for multinominal NB.